How is this sentence divided/ what does it mean? "地形をしており"

展望は美しく、今来た参道と湘南海岸が見下ろせる。
鎌倉は半分に割ったすり鉢のような地形をしており、ここはその山腹に当たる。
木々の頭が揺れ、磯風が森を駆け上がってくるのが見えた。

The character is in a graveyard in 鎌倉. He's gazing at the scenery and describes it as such.
What I'm stuck is, what is the second sentence trying to say exactly?

"展望は美しく、今来た参道と湘南海岸が見下ろせる。"

In the first line he mentions looking at the scenery he just crossed to come here and it's beautiful.

展望は美しく、今来た参道と湘南海岸が見下ろせる。

Then he adds:

"鎌倉は半分に割ったすり鉢のような地形をしており、ここはその山腹に当たる。"
"Kamakura, like a mortar that splits in half..."

I can't make sense of the sentence after it. How to interpret 地形をしており here?

This 地形をする is this する (see also: ~色がする or ~色をする?). 半分に割ったすり鉢 is not "a mortar that split (something)" but "a mortar bowl one has cut in half", i.e., a halved bowl.

鎌倉は(such-and-such)地形をしている。
Kamakura has (such-and-such) a topography.
鎌倉は半分に割ったすり鉢のような地形をしている。
Kamakura has a topography like a halved mortar bowl.
鎌倉は半分に割ったすり鉢のような地形をしており、ここはその山腹に当たる。
Kamakura has a topography like a halved mortar bowl, and this area corresponds to its mountainside.

It would be easier to understand this while looking at Kamakura's actual topography.
